# Extension methods, which is a better choice

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, extension-methods

Following is a test class

```
public class Test
{
   public int a;
}
```

Following are the Extension methods I have created:

```
public static class Extension
{    
  public static void Do1(this Test t,int value)
  {
     t.a = t.a + value;
  }

  public static Test Do2(this Test t,int value)
  {
     t.a = t.a + value;
     return t
  }
}
```

Code Usage:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.a = 5;
```

Both the following calls lead to same result for `t.a, which is 10`:

```
t.Do1(5)

t = t.Do2(5)
```

There are many instances in my code where I need to implement a similar logic, which one is better, one of them is passing reference by value and internally updating it, other is returning the updated reference. Is using one of them safer, if this kind of code ever gets into multi threaded wrapper, provided all the thread safety is taken care of. Normally to update the referenced variable we need a ref or out keyword, which is like pointer to a pointer, instead of a separate pointer to same memory location as in this case, but here in extension methods, I cannot use them. Please let me know if the question needs further clarity

Comment: Ok so there seems to be a confusion of concepts. What you are offering for comparison is a fluent "interface" versus a non-fluent style. Both mutate state via a publicly settable property, both have side-effects, both are extension methods. I personally would only use extension methods for limited sets of reasons (no access to third party code, keeping with a style such as LINQ, etc). To improve your could, you'd make the public property read-only, with a method exposing behaviour that internally handles the value of `a`. If you don't need to expose `a`, also remove the property.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth you are suggesting this is not a good case for extension method, ideally a static method in a class, where I can manage the state of data, to avoid multi threading issue will serve this situation better. Ref and Out came in from the point in such a situation two pointers to same mem location is better or a pointer to pointer to a mem location

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth In my real example, I am working on each element of the List<Dictionary<object,object>, this was just a simple example, in that case would you suggest that Extension Methods would not be of much use

Comment: I can't speak to your question about `ref` and `out` because frankly I don't understand it. I hardly ever use `ref` and try to avoid `out` in favour of other styles. In this case, because it is a state mutator it couldn't be static and encapsulated at the same time, so it would be an instance method. I am not sure where your worry about threading is coming in, thread safety is a huge topic in and of itself.

Comment: It's hard to provide an answer to this as so much depends on how you plan to use this and what context you are using it in.  I'm not sure it is really answerable in its current form.

Comment: Why down vote, at least explain it, what part of question is unclear. I am just breaking it down to simple part and trying to understand what would work, is there something which should not be done at all. Looks like a down voting spree, completely ridiculous :), If I know everything, will not really bother to ask a question

Comment: You just ask which is better and don't even explain what you want to to.  I am not getting why not just a method in Test.

Comment: @Blam I wanted to understand if any of the above implementation has a drawback, which i fail to fathom, there are many parts of the issue, wanted to clearly explain a sub part via simple implementation

Answer (score 4):

In your example it does not make sense to return the `t`variable. `t` is a reference, so setting `t.a` updates the object already. There's no need for `ref`, `out` or returning `t`. One reason for returning `t` would be to allow you to use method chaining.

You only need `ref` or `out` if you want to actually change the reference, not the content of the reference.

Comment: Thanks, I do not need chaining so you suggest the one that has void return type, then I wonder do I even need an extension method

Comment: Well, you never actually *need* extension methods. They are useful if you want to add behavior to objects you can not change the class definition of, but mostly they are syntactic sugar. The difference between a normal static method and an extension method is just the way you can call it in your code.

Comment: In the real life issue, I am trying to create a custom sort for List<Dictionary<object,object>>, since this is altering the behavior, so it would make sense create extension method in this case. I was trying between extension methods

Comment: Well, yes, you can make this an extension method. Or you could use a normal static method you call like `ListSorter.SortList(l);` instead of `l.SortList();`. Or you could simply create a `Comparison` method as seen in this example (which is what I'd have done): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx. If you consider the time you've spent here so far to discuss this issue, you'd have implemented and tested your comparison method three times from scratch by now...

Comment: thanks, true I would have done a better job doing it on my own, rather than having an aimless discussion, but always a learning :)

Comment: Don't misunderstand: I'm all for discussing ideas, but in your case, everything's already there (`Sort` method and a proper description of how to implement a comparison method), so just go ahead :-D

Answer (score 3):

You are actually misunderstanding sense of `ref` and `out` keywords. Those are used, if you want to replace whole referenced object inside your method, for simple property level update they are not needed at all.

In your example, as `Test` is a class (reference type), there is no actual difference between two methods, but returning initial `Test` object as in `Do2` method is just pointless, as object was already updated. So best of two will be the first implementation:

```
public static class Extension
{    
     public static void Do1(this Test t,int value)
     {
         t.a = t.a + value;
      }
}
```

Going back to Do2 method - as I said before, referenced object value is already updated inside a method, so there is even no point in assigning return value to initial variable:

```
t.Do2(5)
```

is the same as

```
t.Do(5)
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but there's a difference between passing reference by value and reference by reference, it is like pointer to same mem location or pointer to another pointer to a mem location, I do understand the usage of ref and out, but here the main question is what is code gets in the multi thread access, would it create difference in the way I am doing it

Comment: I can't say anything about multi thread usage issues, as it depends on what you are trying to achieve. But anyway, with proper synchronization method that returns new instance is always better, if it doesn't confront with meaning of the method.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Well, your code doesn't actually *change the reference*. It changes a value in an object. So the question whether to use `ref` here doesn't even come to mind.

Comment: @ Thorsten Dittmar thanks I got that part, I have realized through a simple test, the actual object I am having List<Dictionary<object,object>> works well if I pass simple reference type, in case I need to change content of the dictionary elements, If I need to change the order, then ref is required for a non extension method / static method